# Flutter class calling another method in another class is failing

Tags: flutter

Why can't class B access class A method? I've imported class A and created an instance of it. theMethod() isn't found. I also tried creating an instance of _AState, still no luck.

> class A extends StatelessWidget{
> @override
> State createState() => _AState();
> }

> class _AState extends State{

> theMethod();

> }

> import 'package:myapp/A.dart';
> class B{
> A a = A();
> a.theMethod(); //The method 'theMethod' isn't defined for the type 'A'.
> }
> '''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why class `B` cannot access the `theMethod()` method of class `A` is because the `theMethod()` method is defined in the `_AState` class, which is a private class.

To fix this, you can either make the `theMethod()` method public, or you can create a getter method in the `A` class to expose the `_AState` class's `theMethod()` method.

Making the theMethod() method public:

```
class A extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  State createState() => _AState();

  void theMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Creating a getter method in the `A` class:

```
class A extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  State createState() => _AState();

  _AState get state => _;

  void theMethod() {
    state.theMethod();
  }
}
```

Once you have made the `theMethod()` method public or created a getter method in the `A` class, you will be able to access the `theMethod()` method from class `B`.

```
import 'package:myapp/A.dart';

class B{
  A a = A();

  void doSomething() {
    a.theMethod();
  }
}
```

Now, when you call the `doSomething()` method on class `B`, it will call the `theMethod()` method on class A.

It is generally considered to be bad practice to access the private members of a class from outside of the class. This is because it can break encapsulation and make the code more difficult to maintain. If you need to access the private members of a class, it is best to do so through a public getter or setter method.